# Create image with html and css table method

Tags: html, css

I want to create image using HTML TABLE and also want to animate it.

But I cannot find anything to slow down the **border collapse** property.

```html
<p class="codepen" data-height="265" data-theme-id="light" data-default-tab="html" data-user="simplyrajatgupta" data-slug-hash="JjRxWYY" style="height: 265px; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; border: 2px solid; margin: 1em 0; padding: 1em;" data-pen-title="Create image with html css, create image with html table">
  <span>See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/simplyrajatgupta/pen/JjRxWYY">
  Create image with html css, create image with html table</a> by Rajat Gupta (<a href="https://codepen.io/simplyrajatgupta">@simplyrajatgupta</a>)
  on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</span>
</p>
<script async src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
```

Comment: You can't. That property cannot be transitioned

Comment: The `border-collapse` cannot be animated but `border-spacing` can be animated which produces the same output, but it will not be helpful to achieve the transition.

Comment: @trickymind  can you please rewrite the code and send me here. Do not say it is big because there is only two css classes

Comment: it's not going to change anything, the only thing i do is to replace the border-collapse with border-spacing check this link : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

Comment: @trickymind please write the css only. You can understand the feeling of a biologist in a mathmatics class [The same is happening with me]

Comment: Here is the link https://pastebin.com/jFUE3izz, note that it's not going to save you, i don't know this property can be animated or not.

Comment: and try this too https://pastebin.com/bMgLqAs2, you can get the similar effect using some jquery libraries also. like pixelate js

Comment: @trickymind Bro! It happened and you can checkout here https://codepen.io/simplyrajatgupta/pen/JjRxWYY and I have credited you also. Thanks for giving your valueable time to me.

Comment: you're welcome. I wonder how did you get each pixel color values from the image?

Comment: @trickymind ! I recently visited your profile and got that you are from Kerela; then I think that you may know hindi? Now come on the point= I got the pixel values using "YS Instant Colour Picker" for Windows http://www.youngsmarts.com/ and I used ClipCloud for Chrome https://clipcloud.catchingnow.com/  to instantly copy the hex color values of the image to my mobile and write instantly. My brother has helped me to do so.

Comment: mm. Interesting. can you please mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do it. you have created the image by using small cells from table and assigning a background color for each cell. And each cell has border spacing you can adjust the space using `border-spacing` property in CSS insted of using border  `border-collapse`

So all you have to do is add a transition for changing the border-spacing property in CSS.

Here is the code to do it:

```
.styled-table,th, td 
{             
  border: 0px solid black;                      
  border-spacing: 10px;             
  transition: all 2s ease;                        
}

.styled-table th,td
{   
  width: 1px;             
  height: 1px; 
}       
  
.styled-table:hover,th, td
{                      
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

*I have reposted this answer because it would be helpful for others too.Thank you*